# AWS S3 access denied to actual object when simulator says access is allowed

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have a user, I'll call Alfred User, with attached IAM policy as follows

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the IAM simulator, I get "Allowed" for GetObject, using this policy, and this ARN: `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/my-object.xml`

On the CLI, I get AccessDenied for the following command: `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket-name/my-object.xml temp/my-object.xml`

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the GetObject
>   operation: Access Denied

I've looked at everything I can think of but I can't explain this discrepancy. What am I missing?

Things I've tried

"creds" here mean "AWS IAM access keys"

- IAM simulator -- this works
- A different set of IAM creds -- this works
- Using `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket-name/` -- this works with Alfred's IAM creds and with my creds
- Compared policies to a similarly configured bucket in a different AWS account. The policies are identical, near as I can tell.

Comment: do you have `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` defined somewhere?

Comment: yes. that's not the problem. i'll add that to the oq

Comment: Does the bucket itself have a bucket policy?  A conflicting `Deny`, there would override an `Allow` elsewhere.

Comment: there is no separate bucket policy i looked at this, too. plus, if this were true then the creds I have that work wouldn't work

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was permissions on the KMS key(s) that encrypt this bucket. The keys are owned by the root account, and as such I couldn't find them with my normal IAM access, nor could I see the policy on them.